# Flexbox not working correctly in IE10+ and Edge // Strange lines appearing on scroll between divs

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10, microsoft-edge

I'm trying so correct the CSS of a blog template in order to comply with the main web browsers.

First : here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seeane/fxc1b1gx/), so you can check the code.

I have two main concerns regarding IE10+/Edge :

Flexbox seems not working like it's supposed to be on IE 10+ and Edge. The footer is over the content and not at the bottom of the page.

Since flexbox is supposed to work with IE10+ and Edge, I don't understand why it's messed up.

a bit of css :

```
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#index\.php,
#single\.php,
#page\.php,
#search\.php,
#error404\.php {
    flex: 1;
}
```

=> The wrapper around the content is set to : flex: 1;

Basically, flex is used right and it works like a charm on Chrome and Firefox.

I tried the tween version of flex with -ms- prefixe. It didn't work either.

Other concern :

I have some strange lines (1px height) that appears on scroll. They appears between divs that have an image background

```
background: rgb(255, 255, 255) url('design/background.png') repeat;
```

On the link [provided](https://jsfiddle.net/seeane/fxc1b1gx/), **if you scroll with  your mouse (not with scroll elevator)**, on IE and Edge, it will show just before "*Articles qui pourraient vous intéresser*" and "*Cet article a X commentaires.*", or for the non French speakers, just before the comment section, at the bottom of the page.

I tried to set a white background and an image background on the parent div (which is wrapping all the .row), but it remains.

Any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to depreciate the template for IE10 and IE11 regarding flexbox (I really wasn't able to make something with it).

For the lines appearing between divs, I simply put a small css rule that remove 1 px above and below in the div's margin :

`margin: -1px 0 -1px 0`

No more line!

I also found out a way to specifically target Edge (that is not mentionned anywhere?)

`html[data-useragent*='Edge']`